# Sending custom data to dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a dialogflow fulfillment service/webhook service that needs to reach into a backend database to pull some data out for a response. The problem is I have to query this database with a specific identifier, is there anyway to pass in a unique identifier when we make a request to dialogflow from a chatbox or a speech request?

Answer (score 0):

In Dialogflow you can send input from chatbox to webhook using query input as well as context.
In your case it make more sense that you pass the data using context in request itself to get the data in webhook.